# Vim folding for HTML5 Boilerplate CSS?

Tags: vim

HTML5 Boilerplate CSS (via initializr, at least) has comments that mark sections, like this:

```
/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 Boilerplate styles - h5bp.com (generated via initializr.com) 
   ========================================================================== */
```

Is there a way to get vim to recognize these as folding sections, so that:

- The first line of `/* ===` is recognized as the beginning of the fold
- The second line, i.e. `HTML5 Boilerplate styles - h5bp...` is the name of the fold
- It folds all the CSS until the next one of these headings

I know I can put `{{{1` on the second line of these comments, but it still looks a little messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is entirely possible, but special, therefore I only give you general hints, not a complete solution.

For the folding, it depends on which other folding requirements you have. Do you still want to fold individual CSS definitions (i.e. `{ ... }` blocks)? In general (unless you use the explicity *fold markers*), you can use either `syntax` or `expr` for `'foldmethod'`.

For example, the [CSS syntax by JulesWang](https://github.com/JulesWang/css.vim) already supports some folding; you'd have to extend this (via `:syntax region ... fold`) for your boilerplate parts (and put this into `~/.vim/after/syntax/css.vim`).

Alternatively, you can write a custom `'foldexpr'`; `:help fold-expr` tells you how.

For the name of the fold, that's determined by the `'foldtext'` setting, which, like `'foldexpr'`, continuously evaluates a Vimscript expression. It's something like this, which checks for the start of the boilerplate block and then returns the next line, or falls back to the default:

```
getline(v:foldstart) =~# '^\s*/\* =\+' ? getline(v:foldstart + 1) : foldtext()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker=/*,*/
```

should work but it would limit your folding ability to comments.

If you are OK with that, you can add those lines to:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim
```

For smarter folding, I'd suggest watching [this screencast by Drew Neil](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/).

Comment: I think the OP wants to fold not just the boilerplate comment block, but all following CSS, too (until the beginning of the text boilerplate).